# Solving $z^5=-16+16\sqrt3i$ using the fifth roots of unity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

> **1** Write down the fifth roots of unity. Hence, or otherwise, find all the roots of the equation
>   $$z^5=-16+16\sqrt3i,$$
>   giving each root in the form $re^{i\theta}$. [4]

In this question, I can work out the answer using de Moivre's theorem, but the question implies that I have to use the 5 roots of unity somehow. Does it just mean that I have to solve the equation in the same way as I solved it for the 5 roots of unity, or whether I have to actually use the 5 roots of unity?

Comment: After more than one month being a member and after asking 8 questions, is about time you learn to use MathJaX

Comment: @DonAntonio But I did it for him!

Comment: @ParclyTaxel So nice of you, yet you are not going to be all the time by his side to fix his posts...are you?

Comment: @DonAntonio As long as I'm on here actually and I find an "interesting" question, then I might fix. Nevertheless, MathJax is something everyone should learn.

Comment: Sorry, I've had my exams for the past month. I shall learn it by next week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus of $-16+16\sqrt{3}\,i$ is $32=2^5$. Setting $z=2w$, the equation becomes
$$
w^5=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i=e^{2\pi i/3}
$$
If $\zeta$ is a fifth root of unity, then
$$
w=\zeta e^{2\pi i/15}
$$
is a solution of the equation. So, if $\zeta_0=1$, $\zeta_1=e^{2\pi i/5}$, $\zeta_2=e^{4\pi i/5}$, $\zeta_3=e^{6\pi i/5}$ and $\zeta_4=e^{8\pi i/5}$ are all the fifth roots of unity, the solutions of your equation are
$$
2\zeta_0 e^{2\pi i/15}
\quad
2\zeta_1 e^{2\pi i/15}
\quad
2\zeta_2 e^{2\pi i/15}
\quad
2\zeta_3 e^{2\pi i/15}
\quad
2\zeta_4 e^{2\pi i/15}
$$
and you can do the final computations.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about your notation.. what does the symbol ζ mean? And how do you go from the first step to the second?

Comment: @Saad Just what it says: if $\zeta$ is *one* of the fifth roots of unity, then $\zeta e^{2\pi i/15}$ is a solution of $w^5=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Thus, using all five of them you can express the full set of solutions.

Comment: Oh, so you do w^5 / (e^2i pi/15)^5 = 1 
Then, you let the L.H.S equal u^5, for example, and then we know the roots of u^5 = 1, so we can find the final solutions.. 
Thank you.

Comment: @Saad Yes, I find five different solutions, so all of them.

Answer (score 1):

From $z^5=-16+16\sqrt3i$ we have $(\frac z {\sqrt[5]32})^5=\frac {-1} 2+ \frac {\sqrt3i} 2$ and $(\frac z 2)^5=\frac {-1} 2+ \frac {\sqrt3i} 2= \cos \frac {\pi} 3 + i \sin \frac {\pi} 3= (\cos \frac {\pi} {15} + i \sin \frac {\pi} {15})^5$

Now making a notation $u=\frac {z}{2(\cos \frac {\pi} {15} + i \sin \frac {\pi} {15})}$ we get $u^5 = 1$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does use the 5 roots of unity, but this is a very roundabout method.. Is there a more direct approach?

Comment: @Saad In fact, the above only shows **one** $\;5\,-$ th root of unity...and thus shows only one single root of the equation.

Comment: @DonAntonio That's wrong. If $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,u_5,$ are the solutions of $u^5 = 1$ then $z_1=2(\cos \frac {\pi} {15} + i \sin \frac {\pi} {15})u_1,z_2=2(\cos \frac {\pi} {15} + i \sin \frac {\pi} {15})u_2, ...$ are the 5 solutions of $z$ equation

Comment: @EugenCovaci How do you *count* the roots?I see **one single** $\;u\;$, as opposed to, for example, the accepted answer where *the five* distinct roots appear. Here there is neither one root times other one, nor powers of one single roots, or moving the argument...

Comment: @DonAntonio It's becoming quite funny ...

Comment: @EugenCovaci Is it? Well, at least that...

Answer (score 1):

$$ z^5=-16+16\sqrt3 i=32\;e^{i\big(2n\pi+\frac{2\pi}3\big)}\\
  z=2\ e^{i\big(\frac{2n}5+\frac 2{15}\big)\pi}$$